# how to make common Drawer for few screens in the app in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Please suggest me a way how can i create common drawer for few screens in flutter.
I have tried this: [Flutter: Setting up a Navigation Drawer with Multiple Fragments (Widgets)](https://medium.com/@kashifmin/flutter-setting-up-a-navigation-drawer-with-multiple-fragments-widgets-1914fda3c8a8). (this makes my whole app with drawer but i want it in on few screens only).
thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Shubham, did you understand the solution provided below?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a class for your drawer (A Stateful or Stateless Widget)

```
class CustomDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Drawer(...);
   }
}
```

And then when using it in each specific page you want:

```
Scaffold(
  drawer: CustomDrawer (...),
  ...
)
```